# malloc boundary sizes: is there a performance difference

Tags: c, malloc

My beginner's class on C has notes which say `malloc` returns a pointer to a block aligned to a 16-byte boundary on x86 machines.

Does that mean that there is no advantage in calling `malloc(1)`, ie the performance would be no different from calling `malloc(16)`?

Comment: I have seen, on occasion, malloc(1). I cringe every time I see it.  It's like using a 40-tonne truck to commute to work.

Comment: That depends on the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I want to understand `malloc` better, not because I need to call `malloc(1)`.

Comment: malloc(1) would be wrong. Even if the architecture aligns blocks on 16-byte boundaries, there's no guarantee you could legally address the following 15 bytes. For example, void *ptr=malloc(1); memset(ptr,0,16); might or might not segfault. And in any case, the assumption's not portable.

Comment: Why do you think ["malloc returns a pointer to a block aligned to a 16-byte boundary on x86 machines" is true?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_a_sucker_born_every_minute) Just `malloc()` the size you need.

Comment: In 32 bit environments malloc typically only returns 8 byte aligned memory allocations. In 64 bit environments however it tends to be 16 byte elignment which is the norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard says

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is **suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

So the pointer alignment is not 16 bytes, but implementation-defined; and on *your* implementation it so happens that there are *some types of objects that are required to be 16-byte-aligned in memory*; and thus pointers returned by malloc are 16-byte-aligned.

However it does not mean that the `char *p = malloc(1)` allocates memory for 16 bytes - on the contrary, you're *not* to touch any memory beyond `p[0]`; `malloc` also needs some internal bookkeeping so it can be that `malloc(1)` consumes a total of 16 bytes of memory, whereas `malloc(16)` would consume 32, or 64; you would not know.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `malloc` does not require it to ask the OS for memory. It asks the OS when required for big chucks on memory and then allocates a bit of that to you. In future calls it will have that bit to spare and can just allocate it to you without the need to asking the OS.

So, it will allocate memory that is convenient to the processor to use - usually aligned.

You should just allocate the memory required and let `malloc` sort out the rest.

Comment: Thanks, but if it will never reallocate the other 15 bytes to anyone else in order to maintain the 16-byte boundary, does that not have the same effect as always working in 16-byte chunks?